# changing the language of app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, feed, android-developer-api

I have some issues with changing the language in the app I do not know why it is not working, there is no error, checked the log all clear.

I want my app to have Spanish and English languages. I have created strings.xml for Spanish and I have set LocaleHelper also I have created app class which contains override method "attachBaseContext" but still not working...

my locale helper

```
public class LocaleHelper {

    private static final String SELECTED_LANGUAGE = "Locale.Helper.Selected.Language";

    public static Context onAttach(Context context) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static Context onAttach(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        String lang = getPersistedData(context, defaultLanguage);
        return setLocale(context, lang);
    }

    public static String getLanguage(Context context) {
        return getPersistedData(context, Locale.getDefault().getLanguage());
    }

    public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }

    private static String getPersistedData(Context context, String defaultLanguage) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, defaultLanguage);
    }

    private static void persist(Context context, String language) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        editor.putString(SELECTED_LANGUAGE, language);
        editor.apply();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }

}
```

my string.xml which is translated for Spanish

```
<resources>
    <string name="item1">Leer Mas Tarde</string>
    <string name="item2">Ajustes</string>
    <string name="item3">Acerca De</string>
    <string name="item4">Términos y Condiciones</string>
    <string name="read_later">Leer Mas Tarde</string>
    <string name="delete">Borrar</string>
    <string name="feedback">Realimentación</string>
    <string name="change_language">Cambiar Idioma</string>
</resources>
```

my app class which extends Application

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, "en"));
    }
}
```

and this is my button click which opens a listed alertdialog to select which language to use

```
private void changeLanguage(){
    btn_changelanguage = findViewById(R.id.changelanguage_button);
    btn_changelanguage.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    builder.setTitle("Select Language");
                    //add a list
                    builder.setItems(name_languages, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            switch (which){
                                case 0:
                                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(context, "en");
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "English selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    recreate();
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    LocaleHelper.setLocale(context, "ca-rES");
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Spanish selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    recreate();
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }) ;
                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

where name_language is:

```
String[] name_languages = {"English", "Spanish"};
```

Comment: why not using strings.xml for spanish and strings.xml english and more strings for others languages ?

Comment: then I have to change every item (button, textview etc) one by one, by settext method... As I read in some blogs

Comment: I think you have to do it, the next time you need you write every text in string resource for easy translate to any language

Comment: yeah I did it like that with translations editor